# pthread library include path on visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, pthreads

I use Visual Studio code on Windows, on an Ubuntu WSL compiler. I keep getting the message "cannot open source file "pthread.h"" on the pthreads library. I can compile the program and it works but I want to see what some of the functions do on the code editor when I hover over it, etc.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for including a local non-compiler-library include file in the current project directory:

```
#include "pthread.h"
```

Similarly, the syntax for including non-compiler-library include files in a distant directory (in unix, replace back (`\`) slashes with forward (`/`) slashes):

```
#include "C:\path\to\my\file\pthread.h"
```

Syntax reserved for include files that are part of the compiler's library directory:

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

One of these syntax methods should resolve the issue.